# Alamofire 4 missing parameters in POST

Tags: ios, post, swift3, parameters, alamofire

Spent hours on this with no success.
I'm using Alamofire to make a HTTP POST to back end server which requires some parameters to be supplied with request.
I'm successfully hitting the server but the server is responding with a 500 stating no parameters were sent?

I've tried most of the SO solutions (changing the encoding type, setting parameters as NSDict, etc) but with no success.

Any help greatly appreciated.

PS its Swift3 with Alamofire 4

Code:

```
let params: [String: String] = ["deviceID": "Some device ID",
                  "email": "email","password": "password","userid": "1234",
                  "username":"gordon"]

let request_params: Parameters = ["LoginUser" : params]

let url = "https://myserver/LogIn" as String

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: request_params, encoding:  URLEncoding.default, headers: [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]).responseString { (response:DataResponse<String>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case.success(let data):
            print("success",data)
            print(response.response)
        case.failure(let error):
            print("Failed!",error)

        }

    }
```

**Update:**

Below is the body of the POST, it looks like this is where the problem exists:

*Alamofire POST body (from above code) -* 
(LoginUser%5BdeviceID%5D=12345&LoginUser%5Bemail%5D=gordon%40test.com&LoginUser%5Buserid%5D=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&LoginUser%5Bpassword%5D=testPassword&LoginUser%5Busername%5D=gordon)

It should be something like (ignoring the encoding values):

*This is a functional post body-*
LoginUser=%7B%22deviceID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22gordon%40test.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22testPassword%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22gordon%22%7D

As you can see the Alamofire post seems to concatenate the LoginUser to start of each attribute? Also missing the LoginUser= at start??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I got this working with the below code, would be very interested in understanding if this is the most efficient means of posting param?

```
let params: NSMutableDictionary? = ["deviceID": "someDeviceID",
                  "email": "emailAddress","password": "aSecret","userid": "12345",
                  "username":"gordon"]
    let url = "https://serverAdrress" as String

    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    let json: NSString! = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    let request_params: Parameters = ["LoginUser" : json as Any]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: request_params, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]).responseString { (response:DataResponse<String>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case.success(let data):
            print("success",data)
            print(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
            print(response.response)
        case.failure(let error):
            print("Not Success",error)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you help me to figure out an issue

Comment: I am sending an request using Alamofire with http body, my request is hitting the server but it always ives me some field missing error

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `JSONEncoding.default` instead of `URLEncoding.default`

Comment: Thanks but I've tried JSONEncoding.default, URLEncoding.httpBody and default all with no success :(

Comment: @ScottishUserHave you tried to send the request to the server using curl or postman, etc? Just to test the API works properly

Comment: You need to print out the POST body and compare it to what you expect.

Comment: @ScottishUser Could you tell me server url, so I can test it

Comment: @DenFav Unfortunately because the URL is the main entry point into app api I cannot share URL.

Comment: It would have helped if you unencoded the % encoding but anyway. I think your good POST body is JSON, or mostly JSON. The JSON root object would be an array or dictionary, which yours doesn't seem to be. OK I see you updated the code. I've never needed to encode in two steps like that. I think AlamoFire does the URLEncoding without being asked for JSON. Your original code but using JSONEncoding is more like what I've used. But that LoginUser= at the start seems non-standard so maybe you need to do it this way. Or maybe it has to do with the Content-Type not being JSON.

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper the server side is .net and is a (sort) of REST api which I think may complicate calls especially with params.